# Firebase Messaging with Javascript Module Bundle - subscribeToTopic "is not a function"

Tags: javascript, firebase, webpack, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have used Webpack to create a module bundle for Firebase Messaging for Web (javascript).

I have everything working correctly except I can't seem to implement the "subscribeToTopic" function.
I followed the instructions on the site [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/send-multiple) , but when I export and run it I get "TypeError: n.subscribeToTopic is not a function".

I suspect I need to include another import for subscribeToToken, but the documentation doesn't tell me. Does anyone know what I can do?

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getMessaging, getToken, isSupported } from "firebase/messaging";

const firebaseApp = initializeApp({
    //all the info here
});

const messaging = getMessaging(firebaseApp);

getToken(messaging, { vapidKey: 'thekeyhere' }).then((currentToken) => {
  if (currentToken) {
    //test - immediately subscribe token to test topic
    messaging.subscribeToTopic(currentToken, topic);
  }else{
     console.log('need to get new token...'); 
  }
 
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log('issupported was false:', error);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the doc you refer to, the [subscribeToTopic()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.messaging.messaging#messagingsubscribetotopic) is a method from the **[Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.messaging)**, not from the JS SDK.

> You can pass a list of registration tokens to the **Firebase Admin SDK**
> subscription method to subscribe the corresponding devices to a topic.

So you cannot call this method from the JS SDK. You can however implement a Cloud Function (Cloud Functions use the Admin SDK) and [call it from your app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable).

Comment: Ah balls! Thanks for the pointer. How annoying.

Comment: Actually it's not that complicated :-) Just take the time to fully understand the Cloud Functions concepts and it will not take that much time. in addition to the Cloud Function doc, I would suggest you watch the 3 videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the Firebase video series: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/